# In game design, do we have to repaint the whole window in every frame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame. Recently I came across a [tutorial](https://nerdparadise.com/programming/pygame/part7) about the code structure of scenes.
However, I am not sure about the overall logic.

```
 active_scene.ProcessInput(filtered_events, pressed_keys)
 active_scene.Update()
 active_scene.Render(screen)
```

In my understanding, it is a bit like CVM model. In the code above, processInput() is to accept the user input. Update() is to update the model(or data) of the game. Render() is to draw the interface according to the updated model.

The part I don't understand is, do we have to draw the view(sorry I don't know its term in game design) based on the entire model? Can we only draw the bit that needs to be changed? For example, if I want to write a [Go game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)). I only need to draw the new piece without having to draw the whole board again. But it means that we have to store not only the model, but the *change* in model. I am not sure if there is an elegant way of doing it.

So my question is:
In design of the game, is it better to update the whole view every frame or only updating the changed bit? How (much) does it affect the performance (processing speed) of the game?

Comment: I think this question should be asked over at gamedev.stackexchange.com. And the answer probably is: it depends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different game engines vary in how they handle screen updates. In some, you can only update the parts of the screen that have changed, which may perform slightly better (since you have less to redraw). But that comes at a cost of complexity, as you need to keep track of what has changed, and what needs to be drawn there.

Redrawing the whole screen is often something you need to be able to do anyway, to draw the initial game state. And in some games, many parts of the screen will be changing on every frame (for instance, in a game where the camera moves). And indeed, you may need to optimize performance mostly for this kind of worst case, where everything is changing at once. The situation where you can get a performance advantage by not drawing large parts of the screen may be a situation where performance is less critical (so you're getting better performance in exactly the cases that don't need it).

To address Pygame specifically, The `sprite.DirtySprite` class lets you mark each of your sprites with a flag that says if it needs to be redrawn. A sprite who's `dirty` attribute is `0` will not be drawn by default (when using one of the `DirtySprite` friendly `Group` subclasses). If you set it to `1`, it will be redrawn once, and then the `dirty` attribute will be set to `0` again. A value of `2` will make the sprite get redrawn always.

But give some thought to whether you actually need to deal with the complexity of keeping track of which sprites are dirty, or whether you can make your code simpler by just redraw everything. If you start simple, you might come back later and add in drawing optimizations if you find you need the added performance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would have to reset the screen every clock tick, not every change in the scene.